# copy a whole folder to SFTP server

Tags: linux, sftp

I need to upload a whole folder to SFTP server. I see one way only - via sftp prompt. So I execute command

```
 sftp> put /var/sites/c/public_html/wp-content/uploads/* /wp-content/uploads/
```

but I get

```
skipping non-regular file /var/sites/c/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2010
```

and no files copying. what is need to do to achieve my goal, upload whole folder(subfolders and files) to the SFTP server.

Comment: As far is i know, that is not possible with `sftp`, i suggest you to use `scp` or `rsync` to copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

`put` is used to upload a single file

to upload multiple files use `mput`

if that doesn't work try switching to scp instead of sftp

Comment: this is hosting server and it allows sftp protocol only. Maybe I can use some tools or so?

Answer (score 0):

`put` supports the `-r` switch on my machine (I'm using `OpenSSH_6.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013`). If your `sftp` doesn't support `-r` you can also use `scp`. This should work as both `sftp` and `scp` use ssh to push files to the remote side, and `scp` is able to push files recursive on almost every system I've seen so far.

Comment: server says `allows sftp connection only`

Comment: That's pretty unusual, have you tried if your openssh does have `put -r`? If not try get your hands on a newer ssh.